# Как сформулировать выражение для проверки условия?

Tags: php, xml

Здравствуйте.

Есть кусок кода, который сканирует каталог и выводит xml-файлы по дате создания:

```
$catid = (isset($_GET['catid'])) ? (int)$_GET['catid'] : 1;

$files = scandir($fileDir);

foreach($files as $num => $file) {
    $full = $fileDir . '/' . $file;
    if(is_file($full)) {
        $articleFile = simplexml_load_file($fileDir . $file);
        if ((string)$articleFile->categoryid == $_GET['catid']) {
            if (!is_dir($fileDir . $file) && !preg_match('/^article.*\.xml$/i', $file)) continue;
            $files[$file] = filemtime($full);
        }
    }
    unset($files[$num]);
}
arsort($files);
```

В каждом xml-файле есть узел `<categoryid>6</categoryid>`, который содержит номер категории. Нужно сформулировать условие, чтобы xml-файлы выводились не только по дате, но и по соответствию номера категории.

Подскажите пожалуйста способ решения этого вопроса.

Comment: загрузите содержимое каждого файла с помощью `simplexml_load_file` и выберете нужный узел.

Comment: К сожалению, не удаётся. Всё равно скрипт считает страницы для всех файлов, не обращая внимание на тег `<categoryid>6</categoryid>`. Изменения добавил в код в вопросе.